# How do you use an if statement to extract a value from a select tag? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, math, parseint

My first input box

```
<input type="number" id="number1">
<br>
<br>
```

My options

```
<input type="number" id="number1">
<select id="operation">  
<option value="add">Add</option>
<option value="subtract">Subtract</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
```

My second input box

```
<input type="number" id="number2">
<br>
<br>
```

This is a button below

```
<button onclick="calculateNum()">Calculate</button>
<br>
<p id="result">This is your result....</p>
</select>
<script>
function calculateNum(){
var operation = document.getElementById("operation").value;
```

In the below code (if statements), do I have syntax errors of any kind?

```
if(operation == "add"){
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
var result = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
else if(operation == "subtract"){
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
var result = parseInt(number1) - parseInt(number2);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the index of selected option and selecting it from options like so:

```
let selectField = document.getElementById('operation');
let operation = selectField.options[selectField.selectedIndex].value;
if (operation == "add") {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes, such as:

- You're defining 2 inputs with ids `number1` and `number2` but you refer to `num1` and `num2`
- You declare `num1` and `num2` variables but you use `number1` and `number2` while parsing.
- You override the plain text in the result object.

I've edited your code. Now you can try it as:

```js
function calculateNum() {
  var operation = document.getElementById("operation").value;
  
  var num1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
  
  var result;
  
  if(operation == "add"){
    result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
  } else {
    result = parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  // or
  // document.getElementById("result").textContent = result;
  // document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1">
<input type="number" id="number2">

<select id="operation">  
  <option value="add">Add</option>
  <option value="subtract">Subtract</option>
</select>

<button onclick="calculateNum()">Calculate</button>
<br>
<p>This is your result: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Comment: Almost exactly the same as the answer I was writing. Only other thing I would was going to mention was a change from `.innerHTML` to `.textContent`.